# designing a real time compute/velocity counter engine

Tags: java, caching, database-design, architecture, system-design

I aim to create a low-latency computing engine tailored for online transaction data. I will extract information such as email, phone number, and customer device from the transaction payload, then compute time-based aggregates, such as the number of transactions associated with a specific email within the past 5 minutes or the number of transactions linked to a particular phone number in the last 10 days.

How should I approach the design of this system?

I tried storing the raw transaction payload in Redis and performing aggregate queries when I received the request. For aggregates with a time window of more than 1 day we computed them offline.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but all you need is a `Transaction` table.

```
Transaction
-----------
Transaction ID
Email
Phone Number
Customer Device
Transaction timestamp
```

where `Transaction ID` is an auto-incrementing primary key and you define another non-unique index on `Transaction timestamp` descending.  The reason we sort descending is so the most recent transactions are in front when ordering by `Transaction timestamp` descending.

Because you're storing timestamps, you can query on specific days and hours.  You just have to generate the appropriate WHERE clause for the time period you're interested in.

You get the count by counting the number of rows you would have retrieved for a particular query.